# Multiple Pointers in Fixed(){} initialized with "new" does not work

Tags: c#, .net, unsafe, fixed-statement

When I try to initialize a new char* array using fixed while being ilitialized allong side other things, it does not work. The following code is an example of that

```
fixed (char* buffer = new char[25])
{
     //This works just fine
}; 

fixed (char* origionalPhrase = phrase, char* buffer = new char[25])
{
    //This does not
}
```

The syntax parser underlines the new char[25] as being "Cannot implicitly convert type 'char[]' to 'char*'". I need both those variables to be initialized as char* arrays. The first variable, origionalPhrase variable initializes just fine. The MSNDN documentation points out that:

```
fixed (byte* ps = srcarray, pd = dstarray) {...}
```

will work.

I used [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f58wzh21.aspx) MSDN article.

Comment: Well, the MSDN example only has one char *, try removing the second one?

Comment: Yup got it. I don't usually use the comma in initialization so I totally forgot that's how you do it. Go ahead throw it up as an answer in case someone comes looking for the answer. You were correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, the MSDN example has only one char * (or actually byte *). Remove the second one.

```
fixed(char* origionalPhrase = phrase, buffer = new char[25])
//                                   ^-- removed char*
{
   // ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
fixed(char* origionalPhrase = phrase)
{
   fixed(char* buffer = new char[25])
   {
   ....
   ....
       now you can use origionalphrase and buffer inside.
   }
}
```

Comment: Just think about the indenting when fixing 100 items.... <shessh>